# Splunk: List indexes and sources to which one has access

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Using this search command

```
| eventcount summarize=false | dedup index | fields index
```

I get a list of all indexes I have access to in Splunk. Is it also possible to get another column besides this within which the source for the index is visible too?

***EDIT:*** It seems like I found a solution:

`| tstats count WHERE index=* sourcetype=* source=* by index, sourcetype, source | fields - count`

This gives back a list with columns for indexes, sourcetypes and sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the permissions to read `sources` are not enforced by the `tstats`, you can `join` to your original query with an `inner` join on `index`, to limit to the indexes that you can see:

```
| tstats count WHERE index=* OR index=_* by index source 
| dedup index source | fields index source 
| join type=inner index [| eventcount summarize=false | dedup index | fields index]
```